# Choosing a Language for GPU Processing

Tags: java, cuda, opencl, gpu

I'm hoping to use Java to use GPUs in order to accelerate computation. I've heard CUDA has Java bindings, but I'm wondering if OpenCL does too? Overall I'm pretty confused about which devices are supported by which, and which is best to use with Java.

Basically, I'm trying to find something that is easily implemented in Java, and can support the most number of GPUs (NVIDIA, ATI, etc). Does anyone have a suggestion of what I should look into to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use Java?

Comment: For portability. I want it to be run on Windows, Linux, OSX, and hopefully embedded devices too

Comment: jocl. look at example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352237/jmonkey-optimization-similar-to-java3ds

kernel is universal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633483/best-approach-for-gpgpu-cuda-opencl-in-java

Comment: arrayfire is going to support all opencl capable devices soon (beta is going to be out later this week). But it is not Java. I don't think Java will be as portable as you think for GPGPU implementations.